# Devtools for R 3.3.0 not working with Rtools 3.3?

Tags: r, devtools

I updated to the latest devel version of R (3.3.0) and the lastest devtools on CRAN (1.7), and got the follow message.

> > library("devtools", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
>
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools
> compatible with R 3.3.0 was found. (Only the following incompatible version(s)
> of Rtools were found:2.15,2.16,3.1,3.3)
>
> Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools from
> http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().

Did I mess something up, or is this just too new for anyone else to have encountered yet?  Seems like Rtools 3.3 ought to be fine for devtools in R 3.3.0.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it unless you actually have issues.  It just looks like devtools hasn't been updated yet https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/rtools.r#L201 Notice there isn't a 3.3 in the version_info list yet.

Comment: Thanks!  It totally slipped past me that this was just a warning.  Duh.

Comment: @Ken. Don't you already have another account on SO? I'm reasonably sure that my  facial-rec wetware is signaling a hit.

Comment: Not so far as I know/not on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue, I resolved it by downloading Rtools 3.3 from this link https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and Installed it in my Windows 8 machine. After that I ran find_rtools() in Rstudio/R, It will return TRUE. Thats it you have resolved it.

Now try library(devtools), it will work :D :D